# VBA Outlook - Replace Paragraph Mark With Manual Line Break

Tags: html, vba, outlook, replace, plaintext

Dear people at Stackoverflow,

I would like to replace for every ***incoming*** e-mail the paragraph marks (^p i believe, at least in outlook Find & Replace) with manual line breaks (^l).
I've not been able to find a solution trough Google, but I might be searching wrong.

I am using the following code as a rule for every incoming e-mail:

(FYI this code works just fine with text)

```
Sub testing(MyMail As MailItem)
 MyMail.HTMLBody = Replace(MyMail.HTMLBody, "example", "changedtext")
 MyMail.Save
End Sub
```

Now I have tried to change the 2nd line to:

```
MyMail.HTMLBody = Replace(MyMail.HTMLBody, "^p", "^l")
```

And

```
MyMail.HTMLBody = Replace(MyMail.HTMLBody, "chr(13)", "chr(10)")
```

But these did not seem to work.

Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with VBA coding.

I've just been told I need to use chr() but I don't have a clue on how to do that.

Some background information:

I am using 2 rules, 1 to change every ^p with ^l and the other rule is to convert the email from HTML to plain text.

If I just convert it without first changing the ^p with ^l it will have all these extra empty lines.

Example:

[image: Example of HTML & when converted to plaintext]
Is someone out there that is willing to help me with this?

I would really appreciate it!

Regards,

Kris

Comment: are you sure that `^p` is 2 characters, and not just a representation of 1? `^` can represent the control key, and `^p` would be the equivalent to ctrl+p (chr(21))

Comment: I'm not really sure about that. Altho when using normal Find & Replace it does work by changing ^p with ^l. Also when I open the source code of an e-mail it's not saved as ^p or ^l since it's in HTML then. Received e-mails will also be in HTML and there it's replaced by a <p> code. I currently have a fix for it but I don't think it will work on every e-mail.

Comment: with chr, you don't need the double quotes , i.e. , you should use `Replace(MyMail.HTMLBody, chr(13), chr(10))`

Comment: @Kris any luck trying my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it, but all with the same side-effect. 
If user SHIFT + ENTER 2 times,  they will result in 1 new line also

Solution 1:
'Replace 2 newline into 1 newline

```
'vbCrLf is actually Chr(13) & Chr(10)

mail.HTMLBody = Replace(mail.HTMLBody, vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbCrLf)
```

Solution 2:
'Replace any extra newline into ""
there will be an extra blank link at the very end

```
tmp = Split(mail.HTMLBody, vbCrLf)
For Each Line In tmp
    If Line <> "" Then
        newBody = newBody  & Line & vbCrLf
    End If
Next
mail.HTMLBody = newBody
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I'm not in today so I cannot give it a try. I will do that first thing tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Kris no problem, enjoy your holiday

Comment: Hello guys, i'm really sorry for the long delay. It's been a busy week with Christmas and all :D (Merry Christmas btw). I have tried your code and it works great!. Thanks again for the great help.