# How do search & replace in email being composed in Outlook 2010 VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm am trying to write some VBA search and replace paragraph marks to manual line breaks in an email I'm composing.

Although I write VBA in Excel, I'm a newcomer to Outlook 2012 VBA.

I'm starting with this code

```
tmp = Split(mail.HTMLBody, vbCrLf)
For Each Line In tmp
    If Line <> "" Then
        newBody = newBody  & Line & vbCrLf
    End If
Next
mail.HTMLBody = newBody
```

which came from [VBA Outlook - Replace Paragraph Mark With Manual Line Break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950252/vba-outlook-replace-paragraph-mark-with-manual-line-break).

I tried changing "mail" to "item.htmlbody" but I'm getting an "Object Required" error.

Can someone set me on the right path with this?

Answer (score 1):

Before processing the current item

Set mail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem